# Does ReSharper find when you delete an item in an enumeration?

Tags: vb.net, resharper

I'm sure at some point we've all written some code like this:

```
For Each datVehicle In datVehicles
  If datVehicle.ID = -1 Then
    datVehicles.Remove(datVehicle)
  End If
Next
```

Which compiles just fine but throws runtime exception because you can't delete an item in an enumeration. Does ReSharper catch things like this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it does automatically, but you could easily create a custom pattern to identify this for you.  See: https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/08/19/highlighting-custom-patterns-with-resharper/

Answer (score 0):

Resharper 6.1 on VS 2010 does not catch it out-of-teh-box. Resharper does not think it is quite Skeet-code tho as it suggests converting to linq.

Answer (score 0):

No version of ReSharper catches this problem.  To create custom pattern that can warn about this condition is not easy because your iteration code can be pretty complex.

If you want to create a custom pattern I would suggest to create a suggestion (may be a warning).  Your pattern would look something like that:

```
$ICOLLECTION$.Remove($arg$)
```

Where $ICOLLECTION$ is an expression of type System.Collections.Generic.ICollection and $arg$ is an argument placeholder.

This way you'll always have a suggestion ( or warning).

I know that the question is about ReSharper only but I want to show the workaround to complete my answer.  The workaround for this problem is to use RemoveAll.  Here's the example in C#:

```
datVehicles.RemoveAll(x => x.Id == -1);
```

Comment: `RemoveAll` is a method on `List<T>`, not `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: @JohnSaunders You are correct but it's very easy to create List<T> as it takes IEnumerable<T> argument into constructor.

Comment: True. If you can accept working on a copy of the original sequence.